# Can a post-build step take me to a specific line of code?

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I just wrote a little program which will be executed as a post-build step when I compile certain projects.

This program returns 0 for success, or some number for failure. In case of failure, Visual Studio then correctly outputs: "The command [...] exited with code *n*."

However, a single number is not always helpful. In my case, I actually want the error to point to a specific place in the source code. Is it possible to output a filename and line number in such a way that Visual Studio will actually let me just double-click on the error and get there instantly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the program you're running is a console application, I think its output will appear in the output pane. If the output is of the form

```
D:\dev\project\Code\MyClasscpp(68) : something terrible happened
```

then you can double-click on the line and the editor will open on the indicated line.

Comment: You can also output to Console.Error for it to show up in the Error List.

Comment: You can also output this format in a Trace.WriteLine while debugging an application. Double-click and all just works.

Comment: Tinister's comment is slightly inaccurate. It will show up in the Error List only if after the filename and line number it also says "Error:" or "Warning:", e.g. D:\dev\project\MyClass.cs(68): Error: Something terrible happened.